# XML stylesheet: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Page x1="71" y1="120" x2="527" y2="765" type="page" chunkCount="1" pageNumber="1" wordCount="1">...</Page>
        <Chunk x1="206" y1="120" x2="388" y2="144" type="unclassified">
            <Word x1="206" y1="120" x2="214" y2="144" font="Times-Roman" style="font-size:22pt">WORD</Word>
        </Chunk>       
</Document>
```

When trying to view it, my browser tell's me I am missing a stylesheet. As I have no previous experience with XML, my question is: how would a simple XSLT (as I understand?) look like, that would enable me to view each element of the XML file in a position given by coordinates in the file. Help greatly appriciated.

Comment: This seems quite possible, but the starting point is to decide what you want the HTML corresponding to this XML to look like. (I assume you have experience of HTML, as without that or XML and XSLT I fear this task is beyond you.)

Comment: @Borodin My XML consists of elements extarcted from a PDF, I would be happy if I could display all the elements in the form of a rectangle positioned using coordinates in the XML. I am not particularly experienced with HTML but I can imagine writing a python script that would translate the elements from XML to html. But it's probably going to be a tedious task :(

Comment: what tool was used to do the extraction? (curious)

Comment: LA-PDFText http://code.google.com/p/lapdftext/ , seems to be working really well.

Comment: Are you in fact trying to render a PDF document in HTML?

Comment: Yes, that is what i am trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML above has errors, you close **Page** twice, and **Chunk** is incorrectly closed with **Chuck**

having a xslt (style sheet) specified on the xml file is optional, the browser is just infoming why he shows raw xml, thats ok.
you can apply xsl styles on server side and decide what sheet to apply, no need to refer it on the xml file.
also you can do xslt translation on client side, this will be more tricky because browser differ the implementation to achieve that.

however if you specify a style sheet all major browsers will translate on client side (old browser don't) but even IE6 does

a link to a style sheet specified on xml file would look like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="so.xslt"?>
```

a style sheet can look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Document">
    <html>
     <head><title>Test</title></head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Page">
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/><hr/>
        Page:<xsl:value-of select="@pageNumber"/>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Chunk">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but as you can see you can build almost anything with that.

Comment: xslt as xml wont admit that kind of error as in your question, they have very strict rules and if you miss it nothing will work. There are online and offline checkers and validators. If you want to discuss details you got to ask something more specific and show more code.

Answer (score -1):

Just add xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" to your html tag. That worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question -- I think he's looking to produce an HTML document out of XML by use of a stylesheet tranform (XSLT). Notice his/her snippet is of an XML doc, not an HTML document as in your answer. The main question as the poster states is "what would an XSLT transform [file] look like". I don't believe that adding the xmlns attribute to anything in the original XML document would remove the message (although using an HTML doc would), and furthermore it would not accomplish the XSL transform.

Comment: no worries. And welcome to SO :D I've definitely done the same thing before. 
Just another comment -- if someone downvotes, you usually lose reputation... you can avoid this by removing the answer if you agree it isn't quite on-topic, or improving the answer. Nice downvoters like me will always leave a comment with a downvote and will remove downvotes if the answer is improved. This helps keeps answers relevant and fewer in number and improves the SO experience.